# Asymptote of solution of a differential equation without solving it

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation (domain $\mathbb{R}$):

$$
u(x) = 1 - u'(x)
$$

and suppose $u(0) = 0$.

How can one prove that $u(x) \to 1$ for $x \to \infty$ **without** solving the equation explicitly?

Comment: The substitution $u(x)=1-v(x)$ may aide your intuition.

Comment: @Semiclassical How does that help? It's just renaming $u'(x)$?

Answer (score 6):

Given the equation

$u(x) = 1 - u'(x), \tag{1}$

with the initial condition

$u(0) = 0, \tag{2}$

I begin by writing it in the more conventional form in which the derivative $u'(x)$ is isolated:

$u'(x) = 1 - u(x). \tag{3}$

Setting

$f(u) = 1 - u, \tag{4}$

we see that $f(u)$ is globally Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $K = 1$, since we have, for any $u_1, u_2 \in \Bbb R$,

$\vert f(u_1) - f(u_2) \vert = \vert (1 - u_1) - (1 - u_2) \vert = \vert u_2 - u_1 \vert; \tag{5}$

(5) in turn implies that (3) has a unique solulution for any initial condition $u_0 = u(x_0)$; furthermore any such solution extends to all $x \in \Bbb R$; these conclusions are simple consequences of the basic general theory of ODEs.

We next observe that, since solutions $u(x)$ of (1), (3) are continuously differentiable, $u'(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$, whence we may conclude from $u'(0) = 1 - u(0) = 1$ (see (2)) that for $\delta \in (0, 1)$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$0 < 1 - \delta < u'(x) < 1 + \delta \tag{6}$

provided

$-\epsilon < x < \epsilon; \tag{7}$

thus for $x \in [0, \epsilon)$ we may write, using $u(0) = 0$,

$u(x) = u(x) - u(0) = \int_0^x u'(s) ds < \int_0^x (1 + \delta)ds = (1 + \delta) x < (1 + \delta)\epsilon < 1; \tag{8}$

if we take $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, i.e., $\epsilon < (1 + \delta)^{-1}$.

We *next* make note of the fact that  the solution $u(x)$ of (1), (3) satisfying (2) cannot take the value $1$ for any *finite* $x_1 > 0$; for if $u(x_1) = 1$ then $u'(x_1) = 0$, and we conclude from this that $u(x) = 1$, $x \in \Bbb R$, is the unique solution such that $u(x_1) = 1$; but this contradicts the hypothesis that $u(0) = 0$; we conclude from this argument that $u(x) \ne 1$ for the solution $u(x)$ obeying (2).  And since by (8) $u(x) < 1$ for positive $x$ sufficiently near $0$, we conclude, using the intermediate value theorem, that $u(x) < 1$ for all $x \ge 0$.  Thus we have $u'(x) = 1 - u(x) > 0$; $u(x)$ is monotonically increasing for all $x \ge 0$.

A calculation similar to (6)-(8) shows that

$u(x) = u(x) -u(0) =\int_0^x u'(s) ds > \int_0^x (1- \delta) ds = (1 - \delta) x > 0, \tag{9}$

valid for sufficiently small $x > 0$; this, combined with the fact that $u(x)$ is monotonically increasing, implies that $u(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$, with strict inequality if $x > 0$.  Though the non-negativity of $u(x)$ is not, strictly speaking, needed for the completion of our argument, it seems to me it is worth noting in passage, since it squares nicely with the overall spirit of *qualitative* analysis which motivates this question.

In any event, we have at this point, without ever *explicitly* solving (1)-(3), shown that:

A.)  $0 \le  u(x) < 1$ for $x \ge 0$, with $u(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$;

B.)  $u(x)$ is a *strictly* increasing function of $x$ on $[0, \infty)$.

From points (A.) and (B.) we conclude that there is an $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ with

$\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x) = \alpha, \tag{10}$

indeed, we may take $\alpha = \sup \{u(x) \mid x \in [0, \infty)$}.  If $\alpha = 1$, then we are done.  If, on the other hand, $\alpha < 1$, then since $u(x) \le \alpha < 1$ we have $-1 < -\alpha \le - u(x)$ or

$0 < 1 - \alpha \le 1 - u(x) = u'(x); \tag{11}$

by (11), we have, for any $x_0 \in [0, \infty)$,

$u(x) - u(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^x u'(s) ds \ge \int_{x_0}^x (1 - \alpha) ds = (1 - \alpha)(x - x_0), \tag{12}$

or

$u(x) \ge u(x_0) + (1 - \alpha)(x - x_0); \tag{12}$

but now by taking $x$ sufficiently large we can force $u(x) > 1$; this contradiction implies we must have $\alpha = 1$.  And we are done.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $u(x)$ is at least $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and that your domain is $\mathbb{R}$ (connected) you have:

$$u'(x)=1-u(x)$$

So $u'(x)=0 \iff u(x)=1$. Also $u'(0)=1$ so we just have to prove that $u'(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x$

But $u'(x)$ is continuous so $u'(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x$ (it can't go to a negative value because it should pass by zero and then the function is constant equal to 1 for all x because of the second derivative). So it's true that $u(x) \to 1$ when $x \to \infty$

You could be a bit more rigorous but at least that's the main idea.

EDIT: I am making use of the next fact:

$$u''(x)=-u'(x)$$

So $u''(x)=0 \iff u(x)=1$

Comment: Would be nice if you could make it more rigerous

Comment: I'll do it when I get home because reading it again I've realized that what I said it's not completely true. Nevertheless, the reasoning can still be applied because if $u(x)>1$ then the derivative is negative.

Comment: Now it's better. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I don't really understand why it is sufficient to show that $u'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ and why this it the case. If $u'(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0$, why is this automatically the case for all $x$?